# How to do string interpolation in a for loop using the indices of a list in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indices, string-interpolation

I have a list and I want to put its elements inside a for loop string like this:

```
my_list = ["Germany", "England", "Spain", "France"]
for this in that:
    do stuff
    print(my_list[0]+ some other stuff)
```

The output should be like:

```
Germany + some other stuff
England + some other stuff
Spain + some other stuff
France + some other stuff
```

How can I loop the indices for string interpolation as well?

Thanks!

Edit: The loop is a bit different. It's more like this:

```
for foo in bar:
    another_bar = []
    for x, y in foo:
        do stuff
        a = object.method()
        another_bar.append(my_list[0]+a)
```

I need to put the strings of lists into the 2nd layer of nested loop. Can't use zip here.

Comment: as I understand this is what you want: my_list = ["Germany", "England", "Spain", "France"]
for country in my_list:
    print(country + 'some other stuff')

Comment: @0x1 I edited your edit to fix indentations.  Please ensure it matches your intent.  Also, your code needs more structure.  For example, `index` is not defined.  Please refer to [MCVE].

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are assuming that `that` is the same lenght as `my_list`.  If so, you can use `zip` to iterate over the two containers in parallel.

```
my_list = ["Germany", "England", "Spain", "France"]
my_other_list = [' is great at football', ' has good years in rugby', ' has Renaldo', ' is, well...']

def foo(bar):
    return bar + '!'

for country, bar in zip(my_list, my_other_list):
    other = foo(bar)
    print(country + other)

# Output:
# Germany is great at football!
# England has good years in rugby!
# Spain has Renaldo!
# France is, well...!
```

Comment: Its a nested loop. I cannot use zip here unfortunately. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in function [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). `zip` allows to process each list in parallel:

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.
>
> Returns an iterator of tuples, where the *i*-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted. With a single iterable argument, it returns an iterator of 1-tuples. With no arguments, it returns an empty iterator.

```
my_list = ["Germany", "England", "Spain", "France"]
for country, this in zip(my_list, that):
    # do stuff
    print(country + that)
```

If your list are of different size, you can use [`itertoos.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables. If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in with fillvalue. Iteration continues until the longest iterable is exhausted.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

my_list = ["Germany", "England", "Spain", "France"]
for country, this in zip_longest(my_list, that):
    # do stuff
    print(country + that)
```

Comment: Its a nested loop. I cannot use zip here unfortunately. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you.

```
for index, this in enumerate(that):
    do stuff
    print(my_list[index]+ some other stuff)
```

Comment: Its a nested loop. I cannot use zip here unfortunately. I edited the question.

Comment: You say you need an index, and I still feel that enumerate can satisfy you.[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate)